# I can't import a module in Python/Windows

Tags: python

I'm having problem when I trying to import a custom module I have which is very simple but I'm always getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo_module1.py", line 12, in <module>
    import mymodule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule'
```

I have tried to set environment variables:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Software\python-3.7.4
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\pyproys\test
```

Everything is located here: 'C:\pyproys\test'

The only way it works is if I add it directly in the code "But I don't want to do it in every single script I have so don't want to maintain it in that way".

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\pyproys\\test')
print(sys.path)
```

Here is the script I'm trying to run:
demo_module1.py

```
import mymodule

mymodule.greeting("Jonathan")
```

'mymodule.py' is in the same folder as 'demo_module1.py'

I'm expecting the code to run fine by just executing:

```
python demo_module1.py
```

Can someone please point me out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `sys.path` before you make any changes to it?

Comment: `'C:\pyproys\\test'` to `'C:\\pyproys\\test'`

Comment: @prashant I don't think that's it. `'\p' == '\\p'`, at least on Python 3.7. Also that string is in the workaround.

Comment: sys.path only throws:
```['C:\\Software\\python-3.7.4\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Software\\python-3.7.4']```

Comment: did you try to add the path to the module to your Windows environment variable `path`? and try to include an `__init__.py` (empty txt file) in your modul's folder?

Comment: Yes I did all of that, path is set corretly and also `__init__.py` in the current folder as well as moved it to a subfolder. Can't see it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the directory */lib/site-packages* in your Python folder in C drive and paste your module in that folder and then restart the system. Hope it'll solve your issue.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work, it looks like that whatever is in sys.path at runtime is the only thing that can discover which I find it very weird since at runtime pythonpath is properly set. Why is that?? why it can't find even though pythonpath is showing the right paths?

Comment: btw. I think it's not the best idea to mix up your own modules with site-packages.